# how to change background color for different user/condition inside html tag in .net with Model value

Tags: html, css, layout, colors, background

I have existing web application built on .NET Framework 4.5.2, we have css file which affects all  views that make use of a main layout `(_Layout.vbhtml)` and `(_XNavigational.vbhtml)` for Navigational panel.
I want  different background colors depending on the user type in the (ul) section

Note: `UserType` can be obtained from Model.

`class="x-navigation"` x-Navigation is already part of css file where background has been set already.

Existing Code:
_XNavigational.vbhtml:

```
@If Model IsNot Nothing Then
    @<text>
          <ul class="x-navigation">
           .....
           .....
          </ul>

  </text>
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

suppose "#32434e" is the already set background color in CSS file,
if new color code is "#8a2d46" then we can write...

```
@If Model IsNot Nothing Then
    @<text>
<ul class="x-navigation  style="background:@IIf(Model.Usertype=1, "#8a2d46", " #32434e")">
....
....
        </ul>

  </text>
End If
```